# Autodesk Forge model derivative manifest api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I am creating a bucket at EMEA region using header (x-ads-region = EMEA). Then uploading a rvt file, then executing svf2 translation.
After that when I am trying to read the manifest from EMEA region url(  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/regions/eu/designdata/:urn/manifest), I receive 404, but when I am trying to read the manifest from US region url(https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest) then I receive the manifest with region US.
Why is so, Is the manifest always being generated at US region irrespective of bucket region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the original designs and their "derivatives" may exist in different geos. In https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure you can see that you can specify the region where the derivatives should be stored, and it defaults to "US".